# Error output when ([D@7852e922) trying to print a double array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I keep having an error like [D@7852e922 when trying to return an array in a method. Please look at my code. (Assignment: updates the Array by replacing all current entries with the value of a and updating it with the value of b.)(only change the method, not the header)

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
 double[] num = new double[]{1,2,4,9,-2,1.2};
 System.out.println(UpdateEntry(num,2,3));}
 public static double[] UpdateEntry (double[] array, int a, int b)
 {
 double[] newArray = new double[array.length];
 for (int j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++){
 if (array[j] == a){newArray[j] = b;}
 else {newArray[j] = array[j];}
 }
 return newArray;
 }
```

The output:

> [D@7852e922

Comment: arrays.toString??

Comment: That is not an error, that is just the output of `toString()` on an array, see the duplicates. In your code, `toString()` is implicitly called on the array by the line `System.out.println(UpdateEntry(num,2,3))`.

Answer (score -1):

just replace this

```
System.out.println(UpdateEntry(num,2,3));
```

with

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(UpdateEntry(num,2,3));
```

here the doc

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(double[])

---

this is a way how to manually doit (taken from the official jdk6)

```
public static String toString(double[] a) {

    if (a == null)

        return "null";

    int iMax = a.length - 1;

    if (iMax == -1)

        return "[]";


    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    b.append('[');

    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {

        b.append(a[i]);

        if (i == iMax)

            return b.append(']').toString();

        b.append(", ");

    }

}
```

Comment: I cannot change the runner (the command in the public static void main). I could only change my method...so how could I change it?

Comment: then you need to return a string object

Comment: and how do I change it?

Comment: please see the update... @JessicaNguyen and tell me if that help